# DirectX - Nothing renders after enabling depth buffer

Tags: c++, directx, rendering, directx-11

I was trying to implement depth buffer into my renderer in DirectX 11.0, but I encountered specyfic problem. I'm new in DirectX so it might be stupid question, but I can't fix it by myself. I checked many tutorials about this topic and each show how to do this more or less the same.

I have got two triangles on the scene. When I enable depth everythink disappers and I have got blue screen (background color) only.

To enable depth buffer I firstly created "Depth Stencil Texture Description" and created "Depth Stencil Buffer" with "Depth Stencil View". Then as last parameter of function OMSetRenderTargets I set DepthStencilView. After that I created  "Depth Stencil State".

```cpp
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilTextureDesc;
depthStencilTextureDesc.Width = width;
depthStencilTextureDesc.Height = height;
depthStencilTextureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthStencilTextureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthStencilTextureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthStencilTextureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthStencilTextureDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthStencilTextureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthStencilTextureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthStencilTextureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthStencilTextureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

hr = Device->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilTextureDesc, nullptr, DepthStencilBuffer.GetAddressOf());
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Logger::Error("Error creating depth stencil buffer!");
    return false;
}

hr = Device->CreateDepthStencilView(DepthStencilBuffer.Get(), nullptr, DepthStencilView.GetAddressOf());
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Logger::Error("Error creating depth stencil view!");
    return false;
}

Logger::Debug("Successfully created depth stencil buffer and view.");

DeviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, RenderTargetView.GetAddressOf(), DepthStencilView.Get());
Logger::Debug("Binding render target output merge successfully.");

D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC depthStencilDesc;
ZeroMemory(&depthStencilDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC));

depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

hr = Device->CreateDepthStencilState(&depthStencilDesc, DepthStencilState.GetAddressOf());
if (FAILED(hr))
{
    Logger::Error("Error creating depth stencil state!");
    return false;
}
```

Then I set viewport depth with this code:

```cpp
viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
```

Then I moved to my Render function and added clearing depth stencil and setting state like this:

```cpp
...

DeviceContext->ClearDepthStencilView(DepthStencilView.Get(), D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

...

DeviceContext->OMSetDepthStencilState(DepthStencilState.Get(), 0);
```

And... It doesn't work. If change last parameter of OMSetRenderTargets from DepthStencilView.Get() to nullptr it works. So it seams like I did somethink wrong with depth stencil, but I'm not sure what. I created gist for this Renderer.cpp [HERE](https://gist.github.com/bilek993/2916758904754dc85acd7257f0aab8ce). Please help me solve this, becase I'm stucked in this and I don't know what to do.

Comment: Have you tried enabling the D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG flag when you create your device? That may give you a hint as to what is going on. The only thing that jumps out at me is if you are using MSAA on your Render Target View, you need to ensure that you use the same MSAA settings on the Depth Stencil View. You also need to use an additional struct when calling the create DSV function called D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC which goes in the middle.

Comment: @GaleRazorwind Thanks, it was a problem with different multisapling settings (count and quality). Anyway, enabling D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG showed me some weird stuff about wrong texture dimensions, so... it wasn't that helpfull for me. You can make an answer to this question to help people in future, because in my opition it's hard to debug and to solve.

Comment: Glad I could help, I may post an answer later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating a Depth/Stencil View, make sure that the MSAA settings for Sample and Count are the same for both the Render Target View and the Depth Stencil View.

The DSV may need additional information when being created for an MSAA target. Here is an example of how my DSV is created (note that I am not using the Stencil Buffer and instead chose to get more precision on my depth buffer):

```
//Describe our Depth/Stencil Buffer
D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc;

depthStencilDesc.Width = activeDisplayMode.Width;
depthStencilDesc.Height = activeDisplayMode.Height;
depthStencilDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthStencilDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthStencilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32_TYPELESS;
depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Count = sampleLevel;
depthStencilDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = qualityLevel;
depthStencilDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthStencilDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthStencilDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthStencilDesc.MiscFlags = 0;

if (MSAAEnabled == true)
{
    //Need a DSVDesc to let it know to use MSAA
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc;
    ZeroMemory(&depthStencilViewDesc, sizeof(D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC));
    depthStencilViewDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D32_FLOAT;
    depthStencilViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2DMS;
    depthStencilViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    dev->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &depthStencilBuffer);
    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, &depthStencilViewDesc, &depthStencilView);
}
else
{
    //Don't need a DSVDesc
    dev->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, NULL, &depthStencilBuffer);
    dev->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencilBuffer, NULL, &depthStencilView);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will summerize what I found with GaleRazorwind help. I fixed my problem by setting depthStencilTextureDesc multisampling values to the same values from BufferDesc.